# I am using Awesome CV, want to add Publons icon

Tags: fontawesome, awesome-cv, academicons

I want to add the Publons icon and link similar to the linked-in style in the header.

I've gone into the .cls file for awesome-cv where there are examples for other platforms but I cannot get it to work for publons.

```
% Defines writer's homepage (optional)
% Usage: \homepage{<url>}
\newcommand*{\homepage}[1]{\def\@homepage{#1}}

% Defines writer's publons (optional)
% Usage: \publons{<userid>}
\newcommand*{\publons}[1]{\def\@publons{#1}}  <=========================What I tried to add

% Defines writer's gitlab (optional)
% Usage: \gitlab{<gitlab-nick>}
\newcommand*{\gitlab}[1]{\def\@gitlab{#1}}

% Defines writer's stackoverflow profile (optional)
% Usage: \stackoverflow{<so userid>}{<so username>}
%   e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/sam-smith
%       would be \stackoverflow{123456}{sam-smith}
\newcommand*{\stackoverflow}[2]{\def\@stackoverflowid{#1}\def\@stackoverflowname{#2}}
```

Comment: If you only add the line you added, what it only does is the define a variable `\@publons` to store your publons id. You need to also add code that parses that id and displays the correct information.

Comment: For example, for homepage, the relevant lines are lines 470--475 in https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls  You can pretty much copy and paste the code making the obvious changes. The only thing not-so-obvious is `\faHome` which you will need to replace by an appropriate fav icon for publons, which you have to look for in the `fontawesome` package documentation yourself.